# How to use md-card in angularjs to have three different sections

Tags: angularjs

First Section of the md-card should be a title,second section should be a content and third section should be the d3.js timeseries graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see an example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'nvd3'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'historicalBarChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 65,
                    left: 50
                },
                x: function(d){return d[0];},
                y: function(d){return d[1]/100000;},
                showValues: true,
                valueFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                },
                duration: 100,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'X Axis',
                    tickFormat: function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
                    },
                    rotateLabels: 30,
                    showMaxMin: false
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                    axisLabelDistance: -10,
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    keyFormatter: function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
                    }
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: true,
                    scaleExtent: [1, 10],
                    useFixedDomain: false,
                    useNiceScale: false,
                    horizontalOff: false,
                    verticalOff: true,
                    unzoomEventType: 'dblclick.zoom'
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                "key" : "Quantity" ,
                "bar": true,
                "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1141102800000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1143781200000 , 0] , [ 1146369600000 , 0] , [ 1149048000000 , 0] , [ 1151640000000 , 0] , [ 1154318400000 , 0] , [ 1156996800000 , 0] , [ 1159588800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1162270800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1164862800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1167541200000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1170219600000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1172638800000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1175313600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1177905600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1180584000000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1183176000000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1185854400000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1188532800000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1191124800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1193803200000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1196398800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1199077200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1201755600000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1204261200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1206936000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1209528000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1212206400000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1214798400000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1217476800000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1220155200000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1222747200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1225425600000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1228021200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1230699600000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1233378000000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1235797200000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1238472000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1241064000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1243742400000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1246334400000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1249012800000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1251691200000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1254283200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1256961600000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1259557200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1262235600000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1264914000000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1267333200000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1270008000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1275278400000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1277870400000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1280548800000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1283227200000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1285819200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1288497600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1291093200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1293771600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1296450000000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1298869200000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1301544000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1304136000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1306814400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1309406400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1312084800000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1314763200000 , 1244525.0] , [ 1317355200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1320033600000 , 475000.0] , [ 1322629200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1325307600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 690033.0] , [ 1330491600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1333166400000 , 514733.0] , [ 1335758400000 , 514733.0]]
            }];
});
```

```css
.carddemoBasicUsage .card-media {
  background-color: #999999; }
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.css"/>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.4/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="carddemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout-xs="column" layout="row">
    <div flex="100" layout="column">
      <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Title section</span>
            <span class="md-subhead">Large</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
          <md-card-title-media>
            <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
          </md-card-title-media>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
          <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
          <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>

      <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Content section</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <md-card-icon-actions>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Share">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/share-arrow.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </md-card-icon-actions>
          <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
          <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>
            The titles of Washed Out's breakthrough song and the first single from Paracosm share the two most important words in Ernest Greene's musical language: feel it. It's a simple request, as well...
          </p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>

      <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Graph section</span>
            <span class="md-subhead">Extra Large</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="space-between">
          <div class="full-width">
            <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
          </div>
          <md-card-actions layout="column">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Share">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/share-arrow.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>

    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much beaver

Comment: Hi beaver,can u please look at this url :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237554/how-to-load-a-d3-js-graph-inside-a-div-using-ng-repeat and help me out ...

Comment: Did you remove the question?